# Qt and UTF-8: strange behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, stream, qdebug

To illustrate my problem I will give you an example:

I have UTF-8 encoded text file.

`in.txt`:

```
ąśćź
ąś
ŻźŹ
```

This program reads `in.txt` line by line and produces duplicate `out.txt`.
It not only duplicates the file but also prints it to console.
At the end it creates `QString` with the same text as the first line of file.

```
#include <QtCore>

int main()
{
    QVector<QString> qv;

    QFile file("in.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return -1;

    QTextStream in(&file);
    in.setCodec("UTF-8");
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        qv.append(line);
    }

    QFile file2("out.txt");
    if (!file2.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return -1;

    QTextStream out(&file2);
    out.setCodec("UTF-8");
    for (int i = 0; i < qv.size(); ++i)
    {
        //Debugging output
        qDebug() << qv[i];

        out << qv[i] << "\n";
    }

    // Important part!!!

    qDebug() << "Why?";
    QString s("ąśćź"); //same as the first line of file!

    qDebug() << s;
}
```

The console output is a mystery:

```
"????" 
"??" 
"???" 
Why? 
"ąśćź"
```

`out.txt`: (duplicate)

```
ąśćź
ąś
ŻźŹ
```

Why does it firstly print "????" to the console while making a duplicate and then prints "ąśćź" when I hardcode "ąśćź" into my program? What seems to be the problem?
It creates identical copy of `in.txt`, so `QString` and `TextStreams` work fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you try to output in.txt or out.txt directly to the console (with something like `cat`)?

Comment: I've been trying to figure out this strange behaviour of qDebug() for 5 hours :)

Comment: qDebug() is for debug messages, not for properly encoded output.

Comment: FWIW, the output on Mac OS X (which uses UTF-8 as its default encoding) is: "ąśćź" / "ąś" / "ŻźŹ" / Why? / "ÄÅÄÅº". If I change the last string (the one in code) to `QString::fromUtf8("ąśćź")`, they all print fine.

Comment: OK but if something is for debug messages, it should have more intuitive behaviour, and not misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no answer to *why* this is happening, but doing

```
for (int i = 0; i < qv.size(); ++i)
{
    //Debugging output
    qDebug() << qv[i].toUtf8();

    out << qv[i] << "\n";
}
```

seems to fix it.